# Use OnClick or hide/show with radio buttons - more than one set within form

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, radio-button, show-hide

I asked this question previously but it was closed as it was deemed too similar to another, however I have looked at the other one as well as many related questions and none really do what I am asking.

I would like a particular div to show or hide depending on yes/no radio buttons. This is within a div that shows up if a particular dropdown selection is chosen.

I really like the onclick and function method that was used for the dropdown box rather than show/hide as it gives the function a particular name and it is easier for me to track. However I am unsure whether this is possible for radio buttons.

I DO already have a similar yes/no choice which successfully does what I want. I used getResults() for the first radio button set, but I am unsure how to differentiate the code for one and call up a particular div, as the solution I got for that one used the id of the radio button but did not ID the div that would show so it would not be differentiated.

I want the text box in the latter div to only show if yes is chosen but I also need it to then disappear if the person changes their mind and chooses no again.
I almost had it but when clicking 'no' the initial question would disappear.
I think all the hide show scripts are somehow interacting too. I will put the script and codes for each below:

Can someone please let me know the code that they would use for my particular values as I really don't know what I am missing.
Basically I need to know if the first set of radio buttons can be distinguished in the script if I use a similar script for the second set of radio buttons.
Also, if it is possible to use a similar function for the dropdowm box but with radio buttons instead.

**1) RADIO BUTTONS ONE:** These work as intended but are not identified e.g. get results by ID

Javascript:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#noowner").click(function () {
        $(".text").show();
    });
    $("#yesowner").click(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
Are you the legal owner?
<label style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; font-size: medium;">
<input type="radio" name="ifowner" id="yesowner" value="yesowner" form="landform" checked>Yes</label>
<label style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; font-size: medium;">
<input type="radio" name="ifowner" id="noowner" value="noowner" form="landform" onClick="getResultsbyID("divowner")">No</label>

<div class="text" id="divowner" style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; font-size: large;">                
Name of Legal Owner<br><input style="height:20px;font-size:12pt; name="actualowner" type="text" id="actualowner" form="landform" size="50">
</div>
```

**2) DROPDOWN BOX OPTIONS:** This is the code for the dropbox which then results in differnt DIVs appearing depending upon the choice made.

Javascript:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>">
    <script>
      function landaccessfunction(){
  getValue = document.getElementById("access").value;
  if(getValue == "road"){
    document.getElementById("roaddetails").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("easementdetails").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("noaccessdetails").style.display = "none";
  }
  if(getValue == "easement"){
    document.getElementById("roaddetails").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("easementdetails").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("noaccessdetails").style.display = "none";
  }
  if(getValue == "noaccess"){
    document.getElementById("roaddetails").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("easementdetails").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("noaccessdetails").style.display = "block";
  }
  if(getValue == "selectaccess"){
    document.getElementById("roaddetails").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("easementdetails").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("noaccessdetails").style.display = "none";
  }
}                </script>
```

HTML:

```
    How is the land accessed?
<select style="height:24px;font-size:12pt;" name="access" 
  id="access" 
  onChange="landaccessfunction()" 
  class="form-control" 
  form="landform">
  <option value="selectaccess" checked>Select One</option>
  <option value="road">Direct road access</option>
  <option value="easement">A legally deeded easement</option>
  <option value="noaccess">No legal access</option>
</select>


<div class="text" id="roaddetails" style="display:none;">


      <label for="roadowner">Who owns and maintains the road?<br>
      </label>
      <textarea name="roadowner" cols="50" rows="2" id="roadowner" form="landform"></textarea>
<br><br>


Access road surface type(s) while approaching land:
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ashphalt" name="roadtype" value="ashphalt" form="landform">
      <label for="ashphalt">ashphalt</label>
    </div>
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="gravel" name="roadtype" value="gravel" form="landform">
      <label for="gravel">gravel</label>
    </div>
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dirt" name="roadtype" value="dirt" form="landform">
      <label for="dirt">dirt</label>
    </div>
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="othersurface" name="roadtype" value="othersurface" form="landform">
      <label for="othersurface">other</label>
<input style="height:20px;font-size:12pt; name="othersurfacedetails" type="text" id="othersurfacedetails" form="landform" size="40" maxlength="40">
<br><br>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="text" id="easementdetails" style="display:none;">
  <label for="easedescr">Easement details (e.g. approximate length, dirt/gravel, through private property, etc.):<br>
      </label>
      <textarea name="easedescr" cols="50" rows="2" id="easedescr" form="landform"></textarea>
<br><br>

</div>
```

**3) RADIO BUTTONS TWO** - if "No legal access" is chosen in the above dropdown box then the third hidden div will show which has the id="noaccessdetails". Within this I wish to have a second question which will then result in a text box if "yes" is chosen. I would also very much like it if NO is the default radio button:

HTML:

```
    <div class="text" id="noaccessdetails" style="display:none;">
  Is there a way to access the property temporarily (e.g. special permission to cross private land)?<br>

<label style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; font-size: medium;">
<input type="radio" name="tempaccess" id="tayes" value="tayes" form="landform>Yes</label>
<label style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; font-size: medium;">
<input type="radio" name="tempaccess" id="tano" value="tano" form="landform" onClick="getResultsbyID("tempaccessdetails")" checked>No</label>
</div>
<div class="text" id="tempaccessdetails" style="display:none;"><textarea name="tempaccessdetails" cols="50" rows="2" id="tempaccessdetails" form="landform"></textarea></div>
```

Javascript that I tried:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#tayes").click(function () {
        $(".text").show();
    });
    $("#tano").click(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

I feel that there should be some ID within the script to ensure only the div with id="tempaccessdetails" will be affected and that when I click no the div above won't also be hidden.

Comment: Just change `$(".text")` to `$("#tempaccessdetails")` in the second example. And change it to `$("#divowner")` in the first example. I think you're just overthinking this.

Comment: On the event declaration `onClick="getResultsbyID("tempaccessdetails")"`, you cannot have double quotes inside. Replace by single quotes `onClick="getResultsbyID('tempaccessdetails')"`. I don't know if solve all stuff, but, try.

Comment: After analyze better, you're right when say that `I feel that there should be some ID within the script...`. Now with `$(".text").hide();` you are affecting all nodes with class `text`. You should use `$("div#tempaccessdetails .text").hide();` To affect only inside of `div` with ID `tempaccessdetails` (On jQuery if you use SPACE between SELECTORs, that means the second inside of the first (but can be multiple levels inside)).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try these things. I may not have time in the next day or two, but will reply and close this question once I have done so.
I really appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: I figured it all out. Thank you so much for the guidance. I did find that I had to enclose the DIV called "tempaccessdetails" within the main DIV "noaccess" or the former would stay visible if another dropdown box choice was subsequentally made, but other than that everything is great. 
Thank you again.

Comment: I should add that I did upvote your answer Barmar but I accidentally 'undid' it and it wouldn't let me select it again which is definitely not a good thing.